# problem with p:blockUI as it is creating two components when I inspect

Tags: jsf, primefaces, blockui

Inside my loader, I have defined a blockUI component with gif graphic as below.

```html
 <p:blockUI block="basis/mad/manuell-queue-parameter.xhtml" styleClass="testAli" id="idAli"  
           widgetVar="blockUi2" >
          <img style="height:8em;background-color:transparent !important;"
          src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/themes/default/pics/loading.gif"/>
 </p:blockUI>
```

I have tried to transparent the graphic and remove border and box-shadow, but in my browser I see two components are created and the css modifications are not applied on the blockUI component.

component 1:

```html
<div id="data:idAli_blocker" class="ui-blockui ui-widget-overlay ui-helper-hidden testAli" style="z-index: 1007; display: none;"></div>
```

component 2:

```html
<div id="data:idAli" class="ui-blockui-content ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-helper-     hidden ui-shadow" style="left: 572px; top: 1338px; z-index: 1008; display: none;">
<img style="height:8em;background-color:transparent !important;" src="/acs/themes/default/pics/loading.gif"></div>
```

css:

```css
.testAli{   
    border:none !important; 
    background-color: transparent !important;
    box-shadow:none !important;
}
```

The first component is a long rectangle and second one is box with graphic. But is css is applied to first Component.

I also tried the inner css for the blockUI but is was not working.

cssOverlay and css attributes were not working.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. For example, what version of PrimeFaces are you using?

Comment: I am using Primefaces V6. I have found that with parent id I can set CSS rules but I could not use blockUI component id for CSS rules.

Comment: blockUI has seen many bug fixes since PrimeFaces 6